# "getAvailableIDs()" in TimeZone class of Android is not supporting 'SystemV' and many abbreviated TimeZones

Tags: java, android, calendar, timezone

> For compatibility with JDK 1.1.x, some other three-letter time zone
>   IDs (such as "PST", "CTT", "AST") are also supported.

This is what Android Developer Document for [TimeZone](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#) says . But the method `getAvailableIds()` is not returning those abbreviations . Which means TimeZone class in Android is not supporting such abbreviations.
Following timezones ids are not supported by Android whereas they are supported in JDK 1.8 :

> SystemV/AST4
>   SystemV/AST4ADT
>   SystemV/CST6
>   SystemV/CST6CDT
>   SystemV/EST5
>   SystemV/EST5EDT
>   SystemV/HST10
>   SystemV/MST7
>   SystemV/MST7MDT
>   SystemV/PST8
>   SystemV/PST8PDT
>   SystemV/YST9
>   SystemV/YST9YDT
>   US/Pacific-New 
>   ACT 
>   AET 
>   AGT 
>   ART 
>   AST 
>   BET 
>   BST 
>   CAT 
>   CNT 
>   CST 
>   CTT 
>   EAT 
>   ECT 
>   IET
>   IST 
>   JST 
>   MIT 
>   NET 
>   NST 
>   PLT 
>   PNT 
>   PRT 
>   PST 
>   SST 
>   VST

Why is it so ?

Comment: Because these are not in standard use.  Even the docs say they are deprecated.  Why do you even want to use them?

Comment: For time being I needed to detect those depricated TimeZone ids which I receive from server in my android client app . I just wanna know how android is able to remove those IDs while JDK still provides it .

Comment: Sounds like you need to handle this on the server side.  They're deprecated there as well.

Comment: Yeah . I agree with you . But can you please explain me how android removed those depricated IDs while Java still holds on it ?

Comment: This isn't a programming question at this point.  If you want to dig through [the tz mailing list archives](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/) you can find history on the systemv and pacific-new stuff.  The others are purely a Java invention, so you'd have to go find some Java forum.  Android != Java, BTW.

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful.  Often the only ones that can answer "why" something is the way it is are the ones who designed it.  I have a similar "why" [question](http://grokbase.com/t/gg/rubyonrails-talk/138p11qy3c/rails-regarding-the-design-of-activesupport-timezone) about Rails time zone aliases that apparently nobody can answer.